# Taking Table Data Dump With Column Name

Tags: mysql

I want a dump of specific table's  data from one DB. 
   I am using the Command
      mysqldump -t -uroot -p TEST Person Address Department > /home/Dumps/Desktop/dumb.sql
   My Problem is the DB which is i am going to import this dump has the same tables but different number of columns. For Example the Person table in New DB contains one more column compare to Test Db's Person Table.
   Because of this i could not import my dump. It shows an error
            "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1"
   I found what is the problem. In dump.sql the insert queries are like

```
INSERT INTO `Person` VALUES 
    (1,'1',NULL,'2012-05-22 08:05:34',NULL,'shobana',NULL),
    (2,'2',NULL,'2012-07-16 09:56:33',NULL,'prabu',NULL);
```

But if it is like this:

```
INSERT INTO `Person` 
   (column1,column2,column3,column4,column5,column6,column7) 
   VALUES 
   (1,'1',NULL,'2012-05-22 08:05:34',NULL,'shobana',NULL),
   (2,'2',NULL,'2012-07-16 09:56:33',NULL,'prabu',NULL);
```

I won't get any problem.

Is there any command to take data dump with column names mapping.

Can anybody please help me? Thanks in Advance..

Comment: it is not a problem of column numbers but order of the columns. Either order your columns in the target database according to the source one (and keep an eye for not null columns) or correct them in the resulting dump file

Comment: @Najzero thanks for your reply.i m sure that the problem is by insert syntax. Why because if i m taking the dump by using phpmyadmin the dump file comes as i want and imported successfully. But by command only it causes some problem like i said.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

use:

```
mysqldump --complete-insert ....
```

This will add the column names and you will be able to import it.